# Select multiple XML childnodes as separate results

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to select data from an XML document. The document is structured as in the following example:

```
<parameters>
    <set>
        <attribId>4711</attribId>
        <attribId>4712</attribId>
        <matnr>000000000001206433</matnr>
        <vkorg>2420</vkorg>
        <spras>NL</spras>
    </set>
    <set>
        <attribId>4750</attribId>
        <matnr>000000000001007885</matnr>
        <matnr>000000000001007886</matnr>
        <vkorg>2420</vkorg>
        <spras>NL</spras>
    </set>
</parameters>
```

The resultset should look like the following

```
attribId    matnr               vkorg   spras
4711        000000000001206433  2420    NL
4712        000000000001206433  2420    NL
4750        000000000001007885  2420    NL
4750        000000000001007886  2420    NL
```

As you can see the nodes attribId and matnr may occure several times. Currently I tried to select the following way:

```
SELECT
  c.value('attribId[1]', 'int')            AS attribId,
  c.value('vkorg[1]', 'char(4)')           AS VKORG,
  c.value('spras[1]', 'char(2)')           AS SPRAS,
  c.value('matnr[1]', 'nvarchar(18)')      AS MATNR
FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/set')      AS t(c);
```

In this select statement the variable @parameters holds the XML document. The result of this is obviously:

```
attribId    matnr               vkorg   spras
4711        000000000001206433  2420    NL
4750        000000000001007885  2420    NL
```

The additional result rows are missing. How would I select to get the first described result set? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may have to look at using a cte to achieve this or get the xml to be formatted with one resultset per parent node.

Comment: We currently use a variation where every "set" node contains only one resultset. But the overhead is too huge to go on with it. How would you use a cte to accomplish this?

Comment: is there an unlimited number of id's that might appear or is it only 1 or 2 per node?

Comment: It is an unlimited number IDs and materials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<parameters>
    <set>
        <attribId>4711</attribId>
        <attribId>4712</attribId>
        <matnr>000000000001206433</matnr>
        <vkorg>2420</vkorg>
        <spras>NL</spras>
    </set>
    <set>
        <attribId>4750</attribId>
        <matnr>000000000001007885</matnr>
        <matnr>000000000001007886</matnr>
        <vkorg>2420</vkorg>
        <spras>NL</spras>
    </set>
</parameters>'

SELECT
    attribId_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS attribId,
    matnr_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS matnr,
    vkorg_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS vkorg,
    spras_node.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS spras
FROM @xml.nodes('/parameters/set') AS s (set_node)
CROSS APPLY s.set_node.nodes('./attribId') AS a (attribId_node)
CROSS APPLY s.set_node.nodes('./matnr') AS b (matnr_node)
CROSS APPLY s.set_node.nodes('./vkorg') AS c (vkorg_node)
CROSS APPLY s.set_node.nodes('./spras') AS d (spras_node)
```

Comment: Wow. This is a slim an effective solution. Do you have a hint on what exactly the part 's (set_node)' does? Thank you alot. Unfortunately I can't mark two solutions as the correct one.

Comment: Sure, the "set_node" is just each instance of the "set" node in your XML.  Then I'm using CROSS APPLY to apply all the values you need selected inside that single node to all other values in only that particular "set" node.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

First select all elements into separate tables (I am just using inline tables) then join them all together based on the set id. In this case I am inferring a set id as it is not specified in your xml.

I am also assuming that there will be at least one value of each column in each set - therefore I am using an inner join

```
DECLARE @parameters xml = '<parameters>
    <set>
        <attribId>4711</attribId>
        <attribId>4712</attribId>
        <matnr>000000000001206433</matnr>
        <vkorg>2420</vkorg>
        <spras>NL</spras>
    </set>
    <set>
        <attribId>4750</attribId>
        <matnr>000000000001007885</matnr>
        <matnr>000000000001007886</matnr>
        <vkorg>2420</vkorg>
        <spras>NL</spras>
    </set>
</parameters>'

select 
    attribId,
    matnr,
    vkorg,
    spras
FROM (  
        select  
            t.c.value('count(for $a in . return $a/../../*[. << $a])','int') as parentID,
            c.value('.', 'int') AS attribId
        FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/set/attribId')      AS t(c)
    ) a
INNER JOIN (
        select  
            t.c.value('count(for $a in . return $a/../../*[. << $a])','int') as parentID,
            c.value('.', 'char(4)') AS vkorg
        FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/set/vkorg')      AS t(c)
    ) v ON a.parentID = v.parentID
INNER JOIN (
        select  
            t.c.value('count(for $a in . return $a/../../*[. << $a])','int') as parentID,
            c.value('.', 'char(2)') AS spras
        FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/set/spras')      AS t(c)
    ) s ON s.parentID = a.parentID
 INNER JOIN (
     select  
        t.c.value('count(for $a in . return $a/../../*[. << $a])','int') as parentID,
        c.value('.', 'nvarchar(18)') AS matnr
    FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/set/matnr')      AS t(c)
 ) m ON m.parentID = a.parentID
```

If there was an id on the set one could do this:

```
DECLARE @parameters xml = '<parameters>
    <set id="1">
        <attribId>4711</attribId>
        <attribId>4712</attribId>
        <matnr>000000000001206433</matnr>
        <vkorg>2420</vkorg>
        <spras>NL</spras>
    </set>
    <set id="2">
        <attribId>4750</attribId>
        <matnr>000000000001007885</matnr>
        <matnr>000000000001007886</matnr>
        <vkorg>2420</vkorg>
        <spras>NL</spras>
    </set>  
</parameters>'


select 
    attribId,
    matnr,
    vkorg,
    spras
FROM (  
        select  
            c.value('./../@id','varchar(200)') as parentID,
            c.value('.', 'int') AS attribId
        FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/set/attribId')      AS t(c)
    ) a
INNER JOIN (
        select  
            c.value('./../@id','varchar(200)') as parentID,
            c.value('.', 'char(4)') AS vkorg
        FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/set/vkorg')      AS t(c)
    ) v ON a.parentID = v.parentID
INNER JOIN (
        select  
            c.value('./../@id','varchar(200)') as parentID,
            c.value('.', 'char(2)') AS spras
        FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/set/spras')      AS t(c)
    ) s ON s.parentID = a.parentID
 INNER JOIN (
     select  
        c.value('./../@id','varchar(200)') as parentID,
        c.value('.', 'nvarchar(18)') AS matnr
    FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/set/matnr')      AS t(c)
 ) m ON m.parentID = a.parentID
```

Comment: That is exactly, what I was searching for. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Could you additionally show a version where you use a set id in the XML. That would help me a bit to understand what is going on ;-)